# python pandas select columns combining list and other column name

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have created a list with 2 column names of a data frame.

Now I want to use this list to select this 2 columns along with other columns.

I have for example a data frame with 5 columns: A, B, C, D, E

I create a list that references A and B:

```
lst = ['A','B']
```

Then when I try to print it adding C I get an error.

```
print(df[lst,'C'])
```

**TypeError: '(['A', 'B'], 'C')' is an invalid key**

Which is the correct way to select the columns in a list along with others?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to pass that as list too;

```
df[lst+['C']]
```